# Gridworkflow intersection with other spatial objects such as a geodataframe

Tags: geopandas, xarray, open-data-cube

I am working with a large [GridWorkFlow object](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/grid-processing/gridWorkflow.html); I am not able to load all the tiles due to in-memory compute resources (24.00 GB mem 8 CPU) and do not need to either. I am interested in intersecting the grid with a spatial boundary I have (GeoPandas GeoDataFrame object) and finding the indices of the tiles which intersect the shapes. Any advice on the best approach? I have a POC for converting the grid to GeoPandas object, but would like to know if it is possible without having to convert, and how I might do that?

```
from datacube import Datacube
from datacube.api import GridWorkflow
from datacube.model import GridSpec
from datacube.utils import geometry

size = (1024*30)
tiles_per_cluster=1
gs = GridSpec(crs=geometry.CRS(102003), tile_size=(size, size), resolution=(15,15))

dc = Datacube(app="my_app")
gw = GridWorkflow(dc.index, grid_spec=gs)

gw.list_tiles(product="landsat7") # breaks memory limits
```

If I index a particular tile, I am able to intersect it with `tile_obj.geobox.extent.intersects(geom_obj)` but I need to be able to do this with all tiles without breaking memory limits.

***EDIT:

```
small_geom = geometry.Geometry(my_polygon, crs=102003)
gw.list_cells(product='landsat7', geopolygon=small_geom)
```

was the final solution I needed. I did not know the kwarg here was "geopolygon" and that it would do the intersect I hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments to GridSpec are all wrong.  Both tile_size and resolution are measured in CRS units and the units for EPSG:4326 are degrees.

So you are asking for tiles that are over 30,000 degrees wide (with pixels 15 degrees by 15 degrees).